# How to create some restrictions for users?

Tags: django

I want to split my application into modules. So each user will have permission to enter certain pages.

There are pages such as;

- Add new user
- See user list
- User Performance
- Assigned customers
- ...

on the menu. For example some users can see one of them and other
users can see 2 of them etc..

Should I create an attribute as `models.BooleanField` for each one and if it is true, user can see otherwise cannot see. I have at least 10 function like this in my menu, I'm not sure it will be the most efficient way.

How can I handle this problem? Is there a better way?

Comment:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use django permissions and check it in your `views.py`:

Creating permissions : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization

Checking permissions : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#the-permission-required-decorator